# C++ - Nothing is displayed in console, no errors displayed, -1 is returned

Tags: c++, debugging

I've recently (very, very recently) have gotten into programming in C++. I'm writing a program to find the highest prime number below `prime`. However, when I execute the code, nothing is displayed, and in the console it says this:

```
Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)   execution time : 0.409 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

I've tried some debugging, and I've figured out the problematic section is lines 17-19 (the `if` statement), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //cout << "maybe here?";
    int prime = 1000;
    //cout << "here";
    while(true){
        //cout << "here2";
        int testr = ceil(sqrt(prime));
        cout << testr;
        bool isprime = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < testr; i++){
            cout << i << " ";
            if(testr % i == 0){
                isprime = false;
            }
        }
        if(isprime){
            break;
        }else{
            prime--;
        }
    }
    cout << prime;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

**Additional Info:**
I'm using Code::Blocks on Mac OSX 64 bit. I'm used to programming in Java, so it may just be a C++ thing I'm unaware of.

Comment: How did you figure it out?

Comment: @SergeyA Basic debugging- comment out things until you find the thing that breaks the code.

Comment: @michal - this is *NOT* a basic debugging, this is called `trial-and-error`. Basic debugging is running your program under debugger, step by step, and examining the values of you variables.

Comment: Take a pencil and go through your program given 1 as an input. See how it misbehaves.

Comment: @SergeyA I see it now. I feel bad for making such a simple mistake.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Noted, sorry for the misuse of terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a few issues.

1) The answer to your question "find the lowest prime number below `prime`" is 2, no programming required.

2) Assuming you want to find the greatest prime number below `prime`, you should test all numbers from `prime - 1`, downwards.

3) The very first iteration of your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testr; i++){
    cout << i << " ";
    if(testr % i == 0){
```

will cause an exception: division by 0.

Comment: My bad. I meant to say highest. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are trying to **divide by 0** in your for loop you should begin with 2. Take a look at this one, it's optimal I guess.

```
bool isPrime(int n) {

  if(n<2)
    return false;

  for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
    if(n%i==0)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is both not optimal and not correct. Test it with `2`.

Comment: It returns true for 2, so it's correct. Could you elaborate your point of view?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the i*i<=n; test. As for optimal, you could check the division by 2 first, then only test the odd numbers. Also, instead of calculating i*i in each iteration, get the sqrt(n) once and compare i to that.